# CreateMutex and OpenMutex return NULL

Tags: c++, windows, mutex, shared-memory

I'm writing an application with shared memory and am creating named mutexes with the appropriate `"Local\"` prefix on the name. However, every time I call the `CreateMutex` function to create the handles, I get a `NULL` return value. I even try calling `OpenMutex` after that and get a `NULL` return.

The `GetLastError()` function returns `6` which means `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. I believe that this happens on the first attempt to create this named mutex in any process. I included `windows.h` after including some MFC components and am using `CMutex` elsewhere in the application; so I don't know if this is a problem or not. I am passing `NULL` and `FALSE` for the first two parameters always and am using Windows XP.

This is a summary of what my code does:

```
char to_name[16] = "Local\\to_1";
d_mutex_to_h = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, to_name);

if (d_mutex_to_h == NULL)
{
   d_mutex_to_h = OpenMutex(NULL, FALSE, to_name);
}
```

Comment: *"If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360)."*

Comment: @AusCBloke I did call GetLastError, the return is in the post

Comment: Ha it is too. I must've missed it or stopped reading when I saw the whole chunk of text. :/

Comment: Note that CreateMutex will open a mutex if it exists - so you shouldn't try to OpenMutex afterwards, this will fail if CreateMutex failed. What was the error return for the createmutex call? (or was the error code for create, not open?)

Comment: Yeah `OpenMutex` is always going to fail in that code, however I'm guessing `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` is from `CreateMutex` not `OpenMutex`, since `OpenMutex` should apparently return `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. If the error is from `CreateMutex`, this is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684315(v=vs.85).aspx) says: *"If lpName matches the name of an existing event, semaphore, waitable timer, job, or file-mapping object, the function fails and the GetLastError function returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE."*

Comment: Why are you compiling your application as non-Unicode (ANSI)?

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not using UniCode, because my app is communicating with hardware that doesn't use unicode and is using classes that might assume the char is only 8 bits.

Comment: @bdonlan okay thanks. I didn't see that specified in the docs even though the method to create mapped memory does specify it.

Comment: @Ian, compiling in unicode mode won't change `char`. It will change the behavior of win32 function calls not decorated with `A` or `W` (ie, `MessageBox` changes, but `MessageBoxA` and `MessageBoxW` are unchanged). Not saying that your reason (compatibility with legacy libraries) is bad, just pointing out that it doesn't change `char` itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation for [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If lpName matches the name of an existing event, semaphore, waitable timer, job, or file-mapping object, the function fails and the GetLastError function returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. This occurs because these objects share the same namespace.

Try using [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657) to see if there's a non-mutex object with the same name.

Comment: Oh, okay. I am using the same name for mapped shared memory. So I suppose that this would cause this.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateMutex()` takes `LPCTSTR` as last argument. This is a macro which is `LPCWSTR` if `UNICODE` is defined, and `LPCSTR` otherwise. However you are passing a pointer to `char` string. It may cause a problem if your program is compiled with `UNICODE` defined.

Try this code and see if it changes anything:

```
d_mutex_to_h = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, _T("your_mutex_name_here"));
```

Comment: This would fail with a compile-time error if this was the problem

Comment: @bdonlan Good point, +1 to your answer. Still there may be a trouble when TCHAR and char are mixed. Compiler would most probably see it tho.